# Does Dharma require the ASAN version of Firefox or will it run with the normal version?

Tags: security, firefox, fuzzing

Does Dharma require the ASAN version of Firefox or will it run with the normal version? Dharma says on it's github page it requires no dependencies but I feel like a fuzzer would require the ASAN version.

Answer (score 1):

From what i see Dharma fuzzer is just an input generator, so it wont not require ASAN, obviously you are more likely to miss bugs without it, so it would be recommended to use ASAN builds. Mozilla recommends to use it together with quokka for catching applications faults / automation which standalone dharma lacks. Regarding Quokka you can see in the config file, a reference to ASAN so here it actually might be required - im not sure, didnt use it yet.

See:
https://github.com/mozillasecurity/quokka

https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2015/06/29/dharma/